# Cannot read TestNG class group from test groups

Tags: testng

I have below code to read groups for test cases for reporting purpose :

```
public void MethodSetup(ITestContext context, Method testMethod) {
        log.info("CLEAR_OUTPUT");
        Test t = testMethod.getAnnotation(Test.class);
        testCaseGroups = t.groups();
        // log.info(t.groups()[0]);//or however you want to use it.
}
```

This works perfectly when I have groups on testcases such as

```
@Test(Groups = "G1")
public void testCase1()
{}
```

but it does not work when I define groups on class level, and throws nullpointer.

```
@Test(Groups="G1")
public class SampleClassTest
{

@Test(Groups = "G3")
public void testCase1()
{
}
}
```

I tried to search google but can not find anything to solve this. Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be used in base class or testcase class. I have base class extended to all testcases classes and this works. I used this method in base class.

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
    public void findClassgoup()
    {
        Test classTest = this.getClass().getAnnotation(Test.class);
        if(null != classTest)
        {
        classLevelGroups= classTest.groups();
        log.info("Classlevel group size : " + classLevelGroups.length);
        }
        if(null == classTest)
        {
            log.info("Test annotation on class retunred null");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do you have other methods without @Test annotation in that test class?**
If so, then when you mark class with @Test annotation, only that class has annotation, **not it's methods**. 
So if you have test class like this

```
@Test(groups="G1")
class TestClass {

     // this test method has no annotation, 
     // but it will run by TestNG because it is public
     // and the class has @Test annotation
     public void testMethod1(){...}

     // this test method would have its own @Test annotation
     @Test(groups="G2")
     public void testMethod2(){...}
}
```

then your `MethodSetup` will throw exception when `testMethod1` is passed.

**EDITED:**
In the case when you get method which have no `@Test` annotation, you can retrieve class-level `@Test` annotation and get it's group.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it but I think  @test can be at both class and test level (https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#class-level). Also test case will be part of both groups if group is mentioned at both places. I have found the solution of this question... I will post it.

Comment: Of course `@Test` can be at both class and method level, but when you add `@Test` on class, it doesn't mean that methods would have `@Test` annotation too.   
P.S. Your post is what I was talking about :D

Comment: Sorry this did not solve the issue because what I wanted to get is - groups name at class. Which is "G1" in your example. Actually it needed another reflection method with @beforeClass using class level annotation. I have also posted that.